# What is significance of a samadhi place?

Tags: belief

What is the significance of a *Samadhi* place of a Saint? Is there any special power or energy around that place?

Comment: The significance of the samadhi place is that it is the place where the saint has chosen to leave His body. Such a place is thereby sanctified by His energy. It is like the place that has been hit by a flood still bears its effects after several years, or the taste of the sweet remains in the tongue even after the sweet has been digested. Though the saint has physically left His body, it still emits strong spiritual energy that can recharge the spiritual batteries of mere mortals.

Comment: @Sai Any references or should we just rely on your opinion?

Comment: @a20 As per your request, here is a reference site that talks about samadhi places and dwells more in detail about its significance and beauty http://soonyata.home.xs4all.nl/jeevasamadhi.htm :). Oh and you need not rely on anybody's opinion. You are free to investigate for yourself and identify what is right and what is not, without relying on any opinions nor anybody's experience. The best knowledge is that which is of direct experience. Anything else is not the same, be it an indirect experience through scripture references, nor through da opinion of me or anyone else :). All the best!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As said by Sai in [comment](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/2902/what-is-significance-of-a-samadhi-place#comment5059_2902), its powerful place. Any rituals/sadhana done near samadhi yields several multiples of actual benefit of the act. Its best place to practice meditation & yoga. Service to samadhi may be considered as service to Guru. Guru is form of God, his adobe is kailsh/vikunta hence its equal important place to worship like other kshetras.

Answer (score -1):

Samadhi is the place where a yogi had attained liberation. After the soul had left the body, the body of the yogi will NOT rot, as in usual case. That is a indication that, that soul is a yogi,and gone into samadhi.

Comment: Welcome To Hinduism SE ! You should cite sources.